# React only renders on server if Javascript is turned off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to run a react app with server-side render.

The issue I'm running into is that with JS enabled on the browser, the app loads without the server being accessed at all.

If I turn off JS, the app will load fine on the server.

Below is app.js on the server.  To be 100% transparent, I began my SSR journey using various examples, tutorials, etc.  I've removed everything I don't think I need and have a fairly understandable server that is handling the rendering, but if something I'm doing doesn't make sense please let me know :)

I have a few simple `console.log()` statements to show on the terminal when things happen.  As stated, if JS is turned off on the browser, I see these fire and log out in the terminal.  If JS is on, they never fire.

I assume I'm missing something really obvious with how things are working.

```js
require('ignore-styles')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const compression = require('compression')
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const React = require('react')
const { Provider } = require('react-redux')
const { renderToString } = require('react-dom/server')
const { StaticRouter } = require('react-router-dom')

const { default: configureStore } = require('../src/store')
const { default: App } = require('../src/components/App')

require('babel-register')({
 ignore: /\/(build|node_modules)\//,
 presets: ['env', 'react-app']
})

// Routes
const index = require('./routes/index')
const universalLoader = require('./universal')

const app = express()

// Support Gzip
app.use(compression())

// Support post requests with body data (doesn't support multipart, use multer)
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// Setup logger (only errors)
app.use(morgan('combined', {
 skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }
}))

app.use('/', index)

// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))

// Always return the main index.html, so react-router render the route in the client
app.use('/', function(req, res) {

 console.log("ON SERVER")

 const context = {}
 const store = configureStore()

 const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html')

 fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {

  if(err){
   console.error('read err', err)
   return res.status(404).end()
  }

  // console.log("PreloadedState:", preloadedState)

  const markup = renderToString(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
     <App />
    </StaticRouter>
   </Provider>
  )

  // Somewhere a `<Redirect>` was rendered
  if(context.url){
   redirect(301, context.url)

  // we're good, send the response
  }else{

   // Inject state and markup
   const RenderedApp = htmlData.replace('{{SSR}}', markup)

   console.log("SSR Render")

   res.send(RenderedApp)
  }
 })
})

module.exports = app
```

**EDIT**

Turns out, the service worker on the client-side was caching the page itself and the server is not actually getting hit.  Hence, the page never renders server-side if JS is enabled.

I began the app using `create-react-app`: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

A default of this boilerplate is to have a service worker registered.  I'm not sure how to disabled the caching of the index page itself while still allowing the service worker to cache assets, etc.

Anyone able to chime in?

Comment: `with JS enabled on the browser, the app loads without the server being accessed at all`. I didn't get this. What do you mean by this?

Comment: I'm using chrome.  If I turn on Javascript on the browser for localhost:3001 (or whatever you are running locally), and then refresh a page within the app, I do not see any `console.log()` statements in terminal.  I would expect to at least hit `console.log("ON SERVER")` since this would be ran every time a route changes.  Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Are you using `react-router` on the client-side as well? If so - you will _not_ get a server-side call on each route change, because the `react-router` package is intercepting route changes, and rendering them client-side. If this is the case, I'll offer some suggestions for how to resolve.

Comment: I am using `react-router` v4.  I don't even see the server being hit when I simply refresh the page.  I read that the client can attempt to render before the server is completely done, but I don't see how that's possibly in my setup where nothing is sent to the browser until all data has been fetched and applied to the components.

Comment: I've updated my question with some recent findings regarding service workers.